# Java-can't make a ball move

Tags: java, eclipse

The problem is that there are no errors,everything works fine,even when i write something  in if(keyevent==w) system.out.println("something"); it works either,but for some reason balls position doesn't change,any suggestion please?

Entity.Java

```
package FirstGame;

 import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Entity {
protected int x,y,w,h;
protected boolean removed=false;

public Entity(int x,int y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

}
public void draw(Graphics g){

}
public int getX(){return x;}
public int getY(){return y;}
public int getW(){return w;}
public int getH(){return h;}

}
```

Player.Java

```
package FirstGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player extends Entity {
public int xd,yd;
public Player(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
    w=16;
    h=16;
}
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
}
private void move(){
    this.x+=xd;
    this.y+=yd;

}
public void setXD(int value){
    xd=value;
}
public void setYD(int value){
    yd=value;
}

}
```

Dodge.java

```
package FirstGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Dodge extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
private int x=5,y=5;
private static String title="Dodge Game";
private static int WIDTH=500;
private static int HEIGHT=400;

private Player player;

// Constructor //
public Dodge(){
    setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    addKeyListener(this);
    player=new Player(200,200);
}
@Override
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0,getWidth(), getHeight());
    player.draw(g);
    g.dispose();
    repaint();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Dodge game=new Dodge();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int c=e.getKeyCode();
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_W){
        player.setYD(-1);

    }
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_S){
        player.setXD(-1);
    }
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        player.setYD(1);
    }
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        player.setXD(1);
    }

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use uppercase for package names.

Comment: okay bro i'm new in java programming soo idk ;d

Comment: (a) In Swing, never override `paint`, only `paintComponent`. (b) Never `repaint` inside `paint` or `paintComponent`, nor call `dispose` on the `Graphics` that you got as a parameter. (c) I see no ball here. (d) there's a `move` but nobody is calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your KeyListener, you don't move the player coordinate. You just set them to the same value. So, it doesn't move.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        player.setYD(-1);

    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        player.setXD(-1);
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        player.setYD(1);
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        player.setXD(1);
    }

}
```

Besides, you don't use `move()` method in `Player` class.
You should remove `move()` and refactor `setXD()` and `setYD()` by methods to increment the coordinates. For example `incrementX(int xValue)` and `incrementY(int yValue)`.

```
public void incrementX(int value) {
    xd += value;
}

public void incrementY(int value) {
    yd += value;
}
```

You have other problems.

As @RealSkeptic explained, "in Swing, never override `paint()`, only `paintComponent()`. Never repaint inside paint or `paintComponent()`, nor call `dispose()` on the `Graphics` that you got as a parameter".

You could override `paintComponent()` in this way :

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    player.draw(g);
}
```

And you could call `repaint()` from the `keyPressed()` method when a move is detected.

At last, `Player` has coordinate fields inherited from `Entity` and declares also its own coordinates. It makes no sense.
And it is error prone. The proof you set coordinate fields of `Player` in the `move()` method but you use the coordinate fields of `Entity` in the `draw()` method.
Either use coordinates from the `Entity` and remove them from `Player` or don't use `Entity` and use the coordinates from `Player`.

Comment: Thanks for help man,i will be eligable to accept your answer in 3 minutes,thanks a lot for explaining and solveing the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added some other remarks to explain other problems. RealSkeptic advises are also good about paint mechanism.